# PHP class returning only one row even after using while() and array()

Tags: php

I have a database with **n** number of rows, but with this class I can only able to get only one result. Here is my function

```
public function payfeeStudent($student) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM regsub WHERE studentid = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $student);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $fees = array();
        while($fee = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()){
            $fees[] = $fee;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $fees;    
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to  get the array

```
require_once '../../functions/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();
$response = array("error" => FALSE); 
if (isset($_GET['student'])) {
    $student = $_GET['student'];
    $fee = $db->payfeeStudent($student);
    foreach($fee as $fees) {
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["subject"] = $fees["subject"];
        echo $response['subject']; //To test
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**
**My table has multiple rows with same studentid**

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM regsub WHERE studentid = ?"` . i think one  `studentid` came only one time in table `regsub`? isn't it?

Comment: no . the regsub contains multiple rows with same studentid @AlivetoDie

Comment: `$fee = $db->payfeeStudent($student);
foreach($fees as $fee) {` don't you think `foreach()` variable is wrongly written ? it need to be `foreach($fee as $somevariable){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** use `fetchAll()` like below:-

```
public function payfeeStudent($student) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM regsub WHERE studentid = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $student);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        $stmt->close();
        return $result;    
    }
}
```

***2.*** Your `foreach()` variable is wrong. It's need to be `$fee` not `$fees`.

Do like below:-

```
require_once '../../functions/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();
$response = array("error" => FALSE); 
if (isset($_GET['student'])) {
    $student = $_GET['student'];
    $fee = $db->payfeeStudent($student);
    foreach($fee as $fe) {
       $response["error"] = FALSE;
       $response["subject"] = $fe["subject"];
       echo $response['subject']; //To test
    }
}
```

Note:- here also in `foreach()` you are over-writing `$response` variable.So please take care of that. (You will get last subject value if you used `$response` outside of `foreach()` loop)

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your answer as the correct one  :)

Comment: @AkshayNShaju  glad to help you. :):)

Comment: @Jaspa I'm using `fetch_assoc()`, Not `fetchAll()` .

Comment: I meant Alive to Die, sorry for not marking it. I proposed using fetchAll() as he does now, until I was told you are not using PDO

Answer (score 2):

```
$fee = $db->payfeeStudent($student);  // this should probably be $fees = ...
foreach($fees as $fee) {
  /* this overrides $response all the time. In the end, in $response will only be the last row of the result: */
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["subject"] = $fee["subject"];

    /* If this is unwanted, better make a new class for the response. Then you make an array of response and always add a new response to the array with a fee and a subject.
Alternatively you can use a two-dimensional array ([['fee', 'subject'],['fee', 'subject],...]), but I wouldn't recommend that */

}
```

Comment: @AkshayNShaju I think you need to combine Machavity's answer and mine. There are several mistakes here. And don't forget to change $fee into $fees (first line in my example)

Comment: Could you give us an update of the code you are currently working with, please?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to chain too much here

```
$stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()
```

`$stmt->get_result()` returns a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. As such, you're fetching an object and *then* fetching the first record. So you'll never get anything except the first record because you're constantly overwriting the object.

Put it outside the loop and it will work like you're expecting

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($fee = $result->fetch_assoc())
```